# How to embed scrollview into tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

Using `UIScrollView` for only horizontal scrolling. Content height and scrollView height is equal. Vertical scrolling would need to pass through to the parent view, to a `UITableView`. How?

Unfortunatelly I can not override, or add extension method to scrollview, so I can not implement this method: `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith`.

Comment: I think are you trying parallex scrolling

Comment: With parallex you suggest to do it programmatically? Create a delegate for scrolling track vertical scroll, and change offset nesting tableview? No easier solution?

Comment: I do use such UIs, the way I am doing is to add the UIScrollView in the tableview cell class, and handle all the scrollview delegate methods in the cell class itself. I don't think you need to do anything to make vertical scrolling pass to parent view, ios will do it automatically as long as you set the content height properly and disable the bounces.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard behaviour for UIScrollView to support nested scroll views, so you do not need to do anything, since UITableView is a descendant from UIScrollView.

[Apple docs, see section Cross-directional scrolling](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/NestedScrollViews/NestedScrollViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008179-CH7-SW2)

> your application does not need to do anything to support nesting scrolling. It is supported and provided by default.

UPDATE:

I tried this as follows, and it works fine to scroll in both directions. You can see the view hierarchy to the left. My test code is below, followed by the output screen after I scrolled each view a little.

[image]

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe cross directional scrolling is supported, but you have not answered how. Could you show an example when scrollview is nested into tableview?